# Combine real objects with real objects in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, oculusquest

I am developing an Unity App for meta quest 3. In my project, I want to use the AR camera to track real objects in a virtual environment.

Considering that meta does not allow access to the oculus camera, I decided to use an external camera as a cameraAR for Vuforia. Thanks to the external camera, I can use ImageTarget or ModelTarget. I am still left with one problem. When I develop in Unity the virtual environment, I have to tell where the oculus camera (OVRCameraRig) is located versus the cameraAR (Vuforia camera). I would like to have them start overlapping, and when I go into play mode, have the overlapping cameras start in an aligned way. However,  Oculus only activates when it is used so this is not possible. Do you have any suggestions?

best regards

Comment: You could have a tracker / image target on the oculus and locate it relative to the external camera -> then in Unity you can invert the calculation and know where your ar camera is relative to the oculus (main camera) so you know where to place tracked objects relative to the external camera

Comment: thanks but it's not a solution. Unfortunately its not allow to have access to oculus camera, so no way to use image target on the external camera